# Move logo next to button into mobile view in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have one small CSS issue that dont know how to resolve myself. I want into mobile responsive view to put logo in top left and move button "Sleva platí také na Beats !" to right so can fit into smartphone screen size. To explain with image what i really need:

[image]

I use this CSS to move logo UP and left:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 100px) {
.logo.is_logo.tip{
float: left !important;
display: table;
margin: -88px auto 14px;
}
}
```

but it seems that in go with values under -88px logo goes bellow header and its not visible. Can someone to give me instructions how to resolve this? [Link](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/) from site where issue is present.

Comment: Add one  more div with logo next to blue button and show in mobile view and hide in desktop view

Comment: Its wordpress site..  i cant make core code changes.

Comment: seems  z-index issue. you need to change in code

Comment: Can you post that as answer pls? What exactly from z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involves to part

1. Javascript - This will be used to move the blue button into the
   desired header location. An if will be used to make it work only on the desired width.
2. CSS - A few rules to adapt the desire look. A media query will make it work only on the desired breakpoint

> JSS

```
window.onload = function() { 
    if(window.innerWidth < 768){
        const sourceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_calltoaction')[0]; 
        const destination = document.getElementById('header');; 
        destination.appendChild(sourceElement); 
    }
}
```

> CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    a.btn_calltoaction {
    background: #070bf7;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    height: 10px;
    }

    header#header {
        display: flex;
            align-items: center;
    }

    .row.clr {
    order: 1;
    }

    #header > .row {
    background-image: url();
    border-style: solid;
    width: auto!important;
    }

    .mobile_nav.isOpen {
    right: 0;
    top: 110%;
    }
}
```

HOPE THIS HELPS :)

Answer (score 1):

you header `z-index` lower than your count div.

Add this style and check. you can see your logo.

```
@media(max-width: 479px){
#header {   
    z-index: 999999;  
}
 .logo.is_logo.tip{
   margin: -40px auto 14px;
 }
}
```

Comment: When add that logo is bellow blue button and its not alligned as image in first post..

Comment: you need to add media query. but it is not solutions.

Comment: I added but not changed nothing it seems.

Comment: I updated my answer again.  you didnt add the css which is mention in your question